# Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

**store.ts**

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer
    },
    middleware: [],
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

**hooks.ts**

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

**authSlice.ts (function that causes the problem)**

```
export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/fetchByTok',
    async () => {
        const res = await getUser();
        return res.data;
    }
)
```

**Auth.ts**

```
const Auth = ({ component, isLogged }: {component: any, isLogged: boolean}) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUser()) // <----------- ERROR
    }, []);

    return isLogged ? component : <Navigate to='/sign-in' replace={true} />;
}

export default Auth;
```

I have a createAsyncThunk function that fetches the user, but I cannot actually put it in the dispatch()...

- Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
- Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)

First time using this, so a nice explanation would be nice :).

Comment: In my case I just updated redux, react-redux, and reduxjs-toolkit versions on package.json, deleted node_modules folder, and ran yarn install.

Comment: I met the same issue and comes here, but all the answers doesn't solve my problem. finally I resolved the issue by comparing to the template project created by CRA using redux-typescript template, checking the types step by step. you can have a try as well: `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript`

Comment: @WayneMao care to elaborate on that comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT!**

Since as mentioned in the comment, redux toolkit actually adds Thunk by default, the answer from Phry is more accurate. I can't delete the accepted answer, so this edit would have to suffice.

**The answer that I provided will remove other middlewares that are automatically added!**

The problem is that you're actually missing the thunk middleware inside store configuration. Just add an import for `thunkMiddleware` and add it in the `middleware` array in your configuration. Since the middleware is not added, the dispatch won't accept the Thunk Action, because it is not supported by redux out of a box.

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer
    },
    middleware: [thunkMiddleware],
});
```

Comment: I added the middleware, but for some reason I'm still getting the same error D:

Comment: So... it's working but vs-code is not happy about it, guess I'll have to deal with it.

Comment: Hmm I would suspect it is more of a vs code problem, maybe restarting it would help? Or checking if vs code is using proper typescript version?

Comment: Thunk is added automatically on `configureStore` call - this approach does not add thunk, but actually removes other middlewares. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 119):

I faced the same issue, for me it was just solved by adding `AppDispatch` to the type of `useDispatch` hook;

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

 useEffect(() => {
 
   dispatch(getUsers()); 
 }, []);
```

getUsers() was my `createAsyncThunk` function

Comment: From where do you import `AppDispatch`?

Comment: @Rafayel https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

Comment: You can set the AppDispatch type in your store file, as described in the docs [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type).  tldr: `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch`

Answer (score 21):

The rest of the answers suggest updating the type of `store.dispatch` by inference, **which I too prefer.**

**Here, I want to suggest an alternative using explicit type definitions if, for some reason, you fail to solve it through inference** (which can happen in larger projects, etc.)

So the idea here is to explicitly define the type of your redux store with an updated dispatch type which supports thunk actions.

### Solution using Explicit type declaration

```js
// your redux store config file.
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import reducers from "./path/to/reducers";

// ... your code 

// 1. Get the root state's type from reducers
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;

// 2. Create a type for thunk dispatch
export type AppThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, any, AnyAction>;

// 3. Create a type for store using RootState and Thunk enabled dispatch
export type AppStore = Omit<Store<RootState, AnyAction>, "dispatch"> & {
  dispatch: AppThunkDispatch;
};

//4. create the store with your custom AppStore
export const store: AppStore = configureStore();

// you can also create some redux hooks using the above explicit types
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppThunkDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Using the above method you can also use `store.dispatch` to dispatch the async thunk actions (might be helpful when you are writing tests)

or use the `useAppDispatch` hook

or use the old school `connect` consumer function from `react-redux`.

It will give you correct types in all the cases.

I personally prefer inference-type declarations most of the time, but sometimes we don't have a choice because of external or internal reasons.

I hope this answer is helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me

```
import {ThunkDispatch} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const dispatch = useDispatch<ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>>();
```

Answer (score 14):

For me the solution was to stick more closely to the RTK documentation example.

So using `concat`...

```
const store = configureStore({
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(FooApi.middleware, apiErrorMiddleware),
  ...rest_of_the_config,
});
```

...instead of spreading the array...

```
const store = configureStore({
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    [...getDefaultMiddleware(), FooApi.middleware, apiErrorMiddleware],
  ...rest_of_the_config,
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Simplest solution for me was to replace:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

with:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch<any>();
```

Comment: This is the worst solution I have ever seen. We use typescript to have types instead of use any

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: what's the point of using typescript is you want to use any?

Answer (score 5):

import * as reduxThunk from "redux-thunk/extend-redux";

Try adding this import statement in redux store configuration file or root file - app.js/index.js or in case of next js - _app.js in pages directory.

eg : store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import * as reduxThunk from "redux-thunk/extend-redux";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
});
export default store;
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out for my case, what if you use `configureStore` from `'@reduxjs/toolkit'` and want to use middlewares, then you can't write something like this:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        r1: r1Reducer,
    },
    devTools: true,
    middleware: [
       reduxLogger
    ],
});
```

instead of this you should use this:

```
 middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(reduxLogger),
```

or use [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73988602/12866263) by [@andrewnosov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087334/andrewnosov)

Comment: Yup, working for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a common TS issue that surfaces like this if you have `redux` in the versions 4.0.5 and 4.1.x both somewhere in your `node_modules`.

For many people, uninstalling and re-installing `react-redux` or `@types/react-redux` seems to solve the problem.

Otherwise your bundler might help you find the source of that problem (`npm ls redux` or `yarn why redux` if you are using one of those two).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any middlewares, don't add it as empty array, just remove it.

If you have some middlewares you have to merge it with default middleware using `concat` method like

```
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(yourMiddleware)
```

Never use spread operator to merge the middlewares. Spread operator will not retain the types but `concat` method does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the [Usage with TypeScript](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript) doc suggest that eventually works for me:

In `store.ts`

```js
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

In `hooks.ts`

```
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
```

In `yourComponent.tsx`

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
dispatch(yourThunkAction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the Redux Toolkit [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) for using `useDispatch` and `useSelector` in TypeScript.

Firstly, export `RootState` and `AppDispatch` from your store.ts file:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
  },
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Then create a hooks.ts file to create typed version of `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks, this basically saves you from extra typing:

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Now you can simply import `useAppDispatch` and `useAppSelector` which are the typed version of `useDispatch` and `useSelector` from your hooks.ts file:

```js
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from "app/hooks";
// ...

export const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const state = useAppSelector((state) => state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, After adding `<any>` issues was resolved.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch<any>();
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You've replaced default middlewares with empty array in your configuration of store. So, your app don't have redux-thunk.

You can do something like:

```
const middleware = [
  ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
  /* custom middlewares */
];
```

and then add this array to configuration object.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with typescript, adding `createAsyncThunk()` types according to docs solved the issue. more info on: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk especially the last parts.