# React Redux: Dispatching createAsyncThunk action throws "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm struggling with an issue related to dispatching an action created with `createAsyncThunk` in my React Redux project. I'm using `@reduxjs/toolkit` for store setup and middleware configuration.

The problem is that when I try to dispatch the action using `dispatch(myAsyncThunk(args))`, I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' > is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnknownAction'. Expected 0 > arguments, but got 1.

Here's the relevant code:

```
export const fetchEquipmentStatusData = createAsyncThunk('onBoard/fetchEquipmentStatusData', async (params) => {
  const response = await axios.get('/api/getEquipmentStatus', { params });
  return response.data;
});
```

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
...
const param = {'equipment': 'car'};
dispatch(fetchEquipmentStatusData(param));
```

I've already configured the store using configureStore from `@reduxjs/toolkit`. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `param`?

Comment: Did you see this about providing a type to `useDispatch`?  I'm not sure what the equivalent would be in your code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143816/argument-of-type-asyncthunkactionany-void-is-not-assignable-to-paramete